# Wordpress as a backend for external service?

Tags: custom-post-types, api

I created php REST API for old windows application of our company.

Through the REST API I display data on a web page.

I want to manage our data through Wordpress, like classic custom post with custom fields

**My concept:**

1. Loading data over REST API into WP backend (I don't want save these data to WP database)
2. Show list custom post (like from Wordpress DB)
3. Edit and Save post to REST API, not to Wordpress DB

It's possible? If so, how?

Comment: What would you even want to use WordPress for? If you're going to bypass all its main functionality.

Comment: seconding what jacob said, this sounds like a solution designed to creat more problems than it solves

Comment: We use Wordpress to manage and display information on our intranet. Manage the data from this Win application (it is not possible rewrite this app, yet) directly from Wordpress, would make it easier for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could create a plugin to produce admin pages that connect to the REST you've made for your application, and provide a gui to interact with its endpoints for CRUD operations. It would be, essentially, no different than connecting to any other external api (i.e. a Mailchimp or Google api).

If you are only looking to provide a gui for interacting with your windows application, there may be less constrictive options. ([ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin) comes to mind)

If, however, your application has other tie-ins to a wordpress install (data lookup relevant to some other content management operation for instance), then look into the [Plugin Developer's Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/).

You may need to create [custom capabilities for user roles](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/) to manage access to your CRUD operation endpoints.

Also see: [Administration menu a page creation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/administration-menus/).

And of course the [HTTP API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/).

Comment: Thank you, for the advice. It seems like a plugin for Wordpress like ng-admin is exactly what we're looking for. Is there a something like "Universal client API" plugin?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. Though I think if you walk through that Plugin Dev guide linked above with what you need in mind, you will see a clear path to make it.